# IQueryable.ToList method messing up with T-SQL sorting order

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF Code First and I have a Entity Framework (against an Oracle Database). For the sake of simplicity, I'll be resuming the scenario. Suppose I have table Products like this:

```
ProductName (varchar)
A
1
C  
2
B
3
4
```

Well, so I build a query using EF:

```
var query = Repo.Products.AsQueryable().OrderBy(p => p.ProductName);
```

When I debug, I get the generated SQL and execute in oracle, everthing is ok, the result set is:

```
1
2
3
4
A
B
C
```

This is right (remember the field is varchar/string) given the order of precedence of characters.

Ok, now if I do the following:

```
var list = query.ToList();
```

The result is:

```
A
B
C
1
2
3
4
```

This is wrong, and different from Oracle result set. If I call ToList() before OrderBy(), the result is ordered correctly, but I do not want to call ToList() before to avoid fetching all the records before filtering.

I'm really getting crazy with this. Anyone can help?

Comment: Is there nothing else happening here? I'm unable to reproduce this on my end.

Comment: Nothing else, every linq query to oracle database places letters before numbers using orderby, even if T-SQL generated is correct and tested ordering perfectly. Getting mad already.

Comment: It seems a problem right inside ToList, when fetching the results and converting them to List of objects. Is there any way to debug ToList method?

Comment: What does query.First() give you?

Comment: I found the problem, please take a look below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The problem was NLS_SORT variable in Oracle. The weird thing was that PL/SQL Manager Developer shows the "right" order, with numbers first, but the reason for the different behaviour is because it changes the NLS_SORT variable session, and Entity Framework doesn't.

I just set NLS_SORT to 'BINARY' before executing any query and that was it!

Solved!

Thanks.